# Jmeter: Beanshell code to get response time of all the Sampler(sum of) under one Transaction controller

Tags: controller, transactions, jmeter, response, beanshell

I need to capture the response time Transaction controller i.e; the sum up response time of  Sample A and Sample B.

Instead of prev.getTime(), do we have any function which will return the transaction response time of a Transactioncontroller ; sum of all the individual sampler under it.[image]

Currently if I give the prev.getTime()  under transaction controller  tree, it will display the individual  response time of  Sample A and Sample B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Get Sample name
 TransactionName = sampleResult.getSampleLabel();
// Response Time
 responseTime = sampleResult.getTime();
// Response  Size
 size = sampleResult.getBytesAsLong();
//Status in true or false
 isSuccessful =sampleResult.isSuccessful();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just `prev.getParent().getTime()` in the [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener).

---

Also consider migrating to [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) on next available opportunity as:

- Groovy is more Java-compliant
- [Groovy scripts can be compiled while Beanshell ones are interpreted each time](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)
- Compiled Groovy scripts can be cached
- [Groovy provides a lot of enhancements on top of Java SDK](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/)
- [Groovy performance is much better](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I don't understand you requirement, you don't need Beanshell to do that.

[Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) will compute that for you.

Comment: Need to post response time of each transaction to Database